# Online audio editor plugin for website

Tags: html, plugins

Is there an audio plugin available that I can simply download and incorporate into a site? This plugin will enable the users to edit audio files on the system. If so please could you send me the link? Thanks - any help or guidance is highly appreciated! I have tried researching the web but I cant seem to find one :)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
 

 </head>

 <body>

  <iframe src="https://twistedwave.com/online/edit"></iframe>
      
        <!-- Instead of an iframe I would like an actual plugin that enables uers to edit the audio files that they upload to the site -->

 </body>
</html>
```

Something like this: https://twistedwave.com/online/

[image]

Comment: Can you please specify more what is the Goal to achieve? and keep in mind that Stackoverflow is not a tutorial website, you should show some effort in coding and we will help you with the best we can

Comment: Thank for the quick response and advise @Pyere - I have tried the best that I can to explain myself in the new edits to the question, so far I just have an iframe that is linked to the twisted wave edit website. But i would like the users to be able to upload and edit audio on the website I am trying to create. I have researched and tried to find options, but I cant seem to find any - this is one of my last options to find an answer. Thanks, and i apologise for how vague I was before hand :)

Comment: Hello @R.jones, well i never did that before but i found a good source where you can download and extension to upload and view your audio file as waveform http://www.wavesurfer.fm/ . I think it is a start

Comment: Thanks for the help @Pyere - This will do great!